# Convert entries of xml file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I  have the following xml file. I want to extract all lines starting with ItemDescription and create a dataframe out of them such that one column contains the color, another the ID, another the Letter and so on. How can I do this?

I tried it with the package `xml.etree.ElementTree` but I could not produce dataframe because I could not access the elements in the desired lines.
I do not want to use `pandas_read_xml` because it works only with pip, I guess.
`pd.read_xml` also does not work even though I updated pandas.
Is there a reliable way to do it with `xml.etree.ElementTree` or with another package that is not too fancy?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<OrderList>
   <ItemDescriptions>
      <ItemDescription Color="rosybrown" ID="0" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="1.67"/>
      <ItemDescription Color="lightcoral" ID="1" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="0.91"/>
      <ItemDescription Color="indiaread" ID="2" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="0.62"/>
      <ItemDescription Color="brown" ID="3" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="2.92"/>
      <ItemDescription Color="firedbrick" ID="4" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="2.34"/>
      <ItemDescription Color="maroon" ID="5" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="0.53"/>
      <ItemDescription Color="darkred" ID="6" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="2.72"/>
   </ItemDescriptions>
   <ItemBundles/>
   <Orders>
      <Order TimeStamp="">
         <Positions>
            <Position Count="1" ItemDescriptionID="9"/>
            <Position Count="1" ItemDescriptionID="18"/>
         </Positions>
      </Order>
      <Order TimeStamp="">
         <Positions>
            <Position Count="2" ItemDescriptionID="9"/>
            <Position Count="1" ItemDescriptionID="12"/>
            <Position Count="2" ItemDescriptionID="14"/>
            <Position Count="1" ItemDescriptionID="18"/>
            <Position Count="1" ItemDescriptionID="16"/>
         </Positions>
      </Order>
   </Orders>
</OrderList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `read_xml` and `xpath`:

```py
>>> pd.read_xml('data.xml', xpath='./ItemDescriptions/ItemDescription')

        Color  ID Letter    Type  Weight
0   rosybrown   0      a  Letter    1.67
1  lightcoral   1      a  Letter    0.91
2   indiaread   2      a  Letter    0.62
3       brown   3      a  Letter    2.92
4  firedbrick   4      a  Letter    2.34
5      maroon   5      a  Letter    0.53
6     darkred   6      a  Letter    2.72
```

Alternative with `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('data.xml')

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(elmt.items()) 
                       for elmt in tree.xpath('.//ItemDescription')])
```

Comment: Thank you but as I pointed out in my post, pd.read_xml does not work for me even tough I updated pandas to the latest version. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Maybe if you use `read_xml` with `lxml` installed, the previous code will work.

Answer (score 2):

Use ElementTree (no external lib is required)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<OrderList>
   <ItemDescriptions>
      <ItemDescription Color="rosybrown" ID="0" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="1.67"/>
      <ItemDescription Color="lightcoral" ID="1" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="0.91"/>
      <ItemDescription Color="indiaread" ID="2" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="0.62"/>
      <ItemDescription Color="brown" ID="3" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="2.92"/>
      <ItemDescription Color="firedbrick" ID="4" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="2.34"/>
      <ItemDescription Color="maroon" ID="5" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="0.53"/>
      <ItemDescription Color="darkred" ID="6" Letter="a" Type="Letter" Weight="2.72"/>
   </ItemDescriptions>
   <ItemBundles/>
   <Orders>
      <Order TimeStamp="">
         <Positions>
            <Position Count="1" ItemDescriptionID="9"/>
            <Position Count="1" ItemDescriptionID="18"/>
         </Positions>
      </Order>
      <Order TimeStamp="">
         <Positions>
            <Position Count="2" ItemDescriptionID="9"/>
            <Position Count="1" ItemDescriptionID="12"/>
            <Position Count="2" ItemDescriptionID="14"/>
            <Position Count="1" ItemDescriptionID="18"/>
            <Position Count="1" ItemDescriptionID="16"/>
         </Positions>
      </Order>
   </Orders>
</OrderList>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = [desc.attrib for desc in root.findall('.//ItemDescription')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
        Color ID Letter    Type Weight
0   rosybrown  0      a  Letter   1.67
1  lightcoral  1      a  Letter   0.91
2   indiaread  2      a  Letter   0.62
3       brown  3      a  Letter   2.92
4  firedbrick  4      a  Letter   2.34
5      maroon  5      a  Letter   0.53
6     darkred  6      a  Letter   2.72
```